# Aligning multi-line lables with inputs

Tags: forms, input, alignment

I run into one tricky task.

I have a form, where form elements are centered. (labels align to right, inputs to left)
Labels are set to some width. Everything styled and looks perfectly aligned when Labels fit into one line.

But as you can imagine, when label won't fit and got split into 2 lines, it's no longer perfectly aligned with the input field.

I couldn't come up with a nice and flexible solution.

Maybe you have a tip for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<td style="vertical-align:middle"><input ... /></td>`?